# Classifying the minimal polynomials of $n \times n$ matrices of rank $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

> Classify the minimal polynomials of $n \times n$ matrices of rank $2$.

It has been hinted that we can assume that A is already in Jordan normal form - as a change of basis won't change the minimal polynomial - and we can thus examine all the possible Jordan blocks by a systematic search. But I don't understand how to utilise this procedure in answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $$J_{m_1}(\lambda_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus J_{m_k}(\lambda_k)$$ is the direct sum decomposition of the matrix $A$ (already in Jordan normal form) into Jordan blocks $J_{m_i}(\lambda_i)$ (respectively of size $m_i \times m_i$ and of eigenvalue $\lambda_i$), then since
$$\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank}(J_{m_1}(\lambda_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus J_{m_k}(\lambda_k)) = \sum_{i = 1}^k \operatorname{rank} J_{m_i}(\lambda_i) ,$$
either:

- exactly one block is nonzero and has rank $2$, or
- exactly two blocks are nonzero, and both have rank $1$.

So, what are all of the Jordan normal form blocks of rank $1$ and $2$? What are the minimal polynomials of the resulting rank-$2$ matrices?

Comment: So I think I know the possible blocks of rank 1: either a single element with the eigenvalue, or a 2x2 block with 1 on the super-diagonal, and 0 on the diagonal. But I'm not sure about all of the possible Jordan blocks of rank 2?

Comment: That's correct for the rank $1$ case. For rank $2$ (and in general), a Jordan block looks like $$\pmatrix{\lambda&1\\&\lambda&\ddots\\&&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&\lambda&1\\&&&&\lambda} .$$ If this matrix has size $m \times m$, what is its rank if $\lambda \neq 0$? If $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: This makes sense. I think there are three possible cases for rank 2: 3x3 with 0 on the diagonal and 1 on the super-diagonal; a 2x2 with a non-zero eigenvalue on the diagonal and a 1 on the super-diagonal, or two separate individual eigenvalues. Each of these cases will presumably have a corresponding minimal polynomial, and these three possibilities will classify those polynomials?

Comment: Yes, that's all of them. Like you say, it's now enough to determine the minimum polynomial for each of the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the minimal polynomial of $A$ is 
$
p(x) = (x - \lambda_1)^{m_1} \cdots (x - \lambda_k)^{m_k},
$
then $m_k$ is the size of the largest Jordan block associated with $\lambda_k$.